# Get current user's data in angularfire2 with Ionic

Tags: angular, firebase, firebase-authentication, angularfire2

**I am searching how to use services to get User's data**

users.services.ts

```
import { AngularFire, AuthProviders, AuthMethods, FirebaseListObservable}     


export class Users {
   uid :string = '8fbEOShqIigfA4u84cyvJcLkv5u1';

    constructor(public af: AngularFire) {}

    getUserObservable(){
        return this.af.database.object('/users/' + this.uid);
    }
}
```

And here my home.ts

```
import { Users } from '../../services/users.service';

@Component({
  selector: 'page-home',
  templateUrl: 'home.html'
})
export class HomePage {
  user: any;
  isAuthenticated: boolean = true;

  constructor(private userService: Users) {}

  ngOnInit(){
    this.userService.getUserObservable().subscribe((userObject) => {
      this.user = userObject;
      console.log("result : ", this.user);
    });
  }

}
```

In console I get :

```
result :  Object {imgLink: "blabla.jpg", money: 0, score: 0, uid: "8fbEOShqIigfA4u84cyvJcLkv5u1", username: "Luis Willnat"…}
```

But in ionic view :

```
Cannot read property 'money' of undefined
```

**I think it's because of something async (which I don't practice well enough) but don't know what ..**

Thank you very much for your help :)

Comment: Well, you need to actually perform the retrieval of the data, now you are only returning `this.user`, which is probably undefined. `getUser` in your service should perform the query and return the user to the component.

Comment: Yeah I saw this 5 minutes after posting. I will look around next hour and will update question if needed, thank you :) !

Comment: Well good that you figured it out! Happy coding! :)

Comment: @AJT_82. The service cannot return the user as it has no idea when it will be available (due to the async call). The service can only return the observable wrapping the user.

Comment: @AngularFrance Yeah, of course I know, seems I wasn't really paying attention here :P Didn't notice the subscribe there... (seems I imagined it was `map`) But thanks for pointing that out! :)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You need to set up your code differently. In general when a service wraps an async calls — *any* async call, not just Firebase's — **its methods should return observables, NOT the values emitted by the observables**.

Even if you wanted to, it's not convenient (or possible) to try and return the values wrapped in an observable as they are available only when the observable emits, and you have no control over when that will be.

As per these guidelines your code becomes:

```ts
@Injectable()
export class UserService {
  constructor(public af: AngularFire) {}
  getUser() {
    // Return the observable. DO NOT subscribe here.
    return this.af.auth;
    // Hint: you could also transform the value before returning it:
    // return this.af.auth.map(authData => new User({name: authData.name}));
  }
}
```

Then, in your component or wherever you need to, you subscribe to obtain the user:

```ts
ngOnInit() {
  this.userService.getUser()
    .subscribe(user => this.user = user);
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much first of all ! I learned something from you !
I will maybe update my code in this question, because I solved this problem, but I think I stil have one little problem, probably because of aysnc ..

Comment: You're welcome. The problem that you still have is indeed due to asynchronicity. In your template, you're probably trying to display user properties such as `{{ user.money }}` but `user` is initially not defined. You need to *guard* the error by writing `user?` every time you interpolate a user property (i.e. `{{ user?.money }}`). ALTERNATIVELY you can wrap all the `{{ user.prop }}` interpolations in ONE big `<div *ngIf="user">...</div>`. If you think the answer is satisfying, please consider marking it as accepted, thanks. :)

Comment: Woow merci beaucoup, c'est la plus belle chose qui m'arrive aujourd'hui :D 
Thank you very much, you really helped me, I appreciate it ! :)